# How to show custom callout view click on flag like this given image

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am iOS developer. I am trying to show custom callout view click on (pin).This callout view is contain two button. I have been tried to show custom callout view with these below given code.

```
       func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

    var calloutSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 110.0)
    confirm = MKAnnotationView(frame: CGRect(x: -calloutSize.width/2, y: -calloutSize.height - 10, width: calloutSize.width, height:calloutSize.height))

    confirm!.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
    confirm!.alpha = 0.7


    let button_Yes = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 54))
    button_Yes.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    button_Yes.setTitle("See listing detail", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button_Yes.addTarget(self, action:Selector( "checkout:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button_Yes.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button_Yes.tag = 1
    confirm!.addSubview(button_Yes)

    let button_No = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,calloutSize.height / 2, 200, 54))

    button_No.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    button_No.setTitle("Get directions", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button_No.addTarget(self, action:Selector("checkin:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button_No.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button_No.tag = 2
    confirm!.addSubview(button_No)

    view.addSubview(confirm!)
```

}

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

    confirm!.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

[I have embedded a image url, i want to like this callout](http://s14.postimg.org/yjk63wxc1/yardsailor_MAP_flagselect.jpg)

Comment: So what's the exact problem or question?  By the way, I suggest using a plain UIView instead of creating an MKAnnotationView for the callout view.

Comment: The exact problem is that, when am i select pin then a custom annotation show with two button like row. And i am also use UIView but this is not working. Please look a image url for your understanding.

Comment: You need to explain in detail what "not working" means.  Compiler error, run-time error, something else -- be precise -- what happens exactly?  What debugging did you do?  Using an MKAnnotationView for the _callout_ view is not recommended.

Comment: My callout view are showing click on pin but these button action not per form and there is not generating error. when i am click on button then callout view remove from map view.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066623/customise-ios8-callout-bubble-swift.  Implement hitTest inside a custom MKAnnotationView (but notice the _callout_ view the annotation view creates is a UIView).

Comment: and please look the image url@

Comment: i have face a error: use of unresolved identifier "updatePinPosition"

Comment: and where this code put.. @if calloutState == .Expanded && CGRectContainsPoint(tableView.frame, viewPoint) {
    view = tableView.hitTest(convertPoint(viewPoint, toView: tableView), withEvent: event)
}

Comment: This code is not working.

Comment: any body help me,  to make a callout view on annotation selected. i have attached image for your better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to create subclass of `MKAnnotationView` and XIB,
Using this you can return your custom view for callout in

```
mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)
```

Here are the best examples : 
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gikanimatedcallout
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multirowcalloutannotationview

Comment: I can't use third party library.

Comment: create subclass of MKAnnotationView and XIB, or At least you can use the pattern they have used(third parties).

Comment: I am working on swift language and latest storyboard.

Comment: you have to make subclass of MKAnnotationView and XIB for that, because MKAnnotationView is a subclass of UIView. Or you can put just a view in your Scene's header in storyboard, and set you custom class to that view. About "Swift" language, I am not talking about syntax, I am just talking about logic and pattern

Comment: Please give me a code of  MKAnnotationview( subclass) .